# How many integers between $1$ and $10^4$ contain exactly one $8$ and one $9$?

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, education

I have this problem: How many integers between $1$ and $10^4$ contain exactly one $8$ and one $9$?, but i dont know if $18, 19, 28, 29...$ serve, else it could be $8$ y $9 = 2$ numbers, help please.

Comment: Hi @asdfg. You can increase your chance to get help if you tell us what did you do so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: well first i dont know very well the question, the numbers must be only 8 and 9 if there are two numbers 8 and 9 truth?

Comment: Considering the statment, it seems the number has to contain both numbers ($8$ and $9$). For instance, you should consider numbers like $89, 98, 189, 198,...$. In addition, $18,19,28,29$ should not be considered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that $10,000$ does not have this property. Therefore, we only have to consider the numbers $1$ through $9999$, each of which have $4$ digits, including leading zeroes:
$$
\big(\quad\big)\big(\quad\big)\big(\quad\big)\big(\quad\big)
$$
We can place a $9$ in any of the blank spaces, so there are $4$ ways to do this. Then, once the $9$ has been placed, there are $3$ places where the $8$ can be placed. The last $2$ digits can be anything, *except* that we can't have any more $8$'s or $9$'s. So there are $8$ different digits that we can use in both cases. Therefore, the number of combinations equals
$$
4 \times 3 \times 8 \times 8 = 768.
$$