# How many integers between 1 and $10^4$ contain exactly one 8 and one 9?

Tags: calculus, probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

question: How many integers between 1 and $10^4$ contain exactly one 8 and one 9?

I try do this, but i don't know if this is good, i ask my teacher and she says this:  IN A_3 more accounts look at lines 2 and 4 from bottom to top are the same numbers,    I advise you to ask yourself first about the ways to put 8, 9 and then the remaining numbers.

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYyem.png)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Igat1.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many integers between $1$ and $10^4$ contain exactly one $8$ and one $9$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3864493/how-many-integers-between-1-and-104-contain-exactly-one-8-and-one-9)

Comment: well, but i am doing a different way, i need to resover in that way

Comment: Your comment to one of the answers raises a good point.  If you are trying to solve it one way, you would prefer it if someone could show you how to complete the problem with the approach that you started.  For this query, there are two problems: (1) I (for one) had trouble examining your work.  The images need to be replaced by you writing the math directly into your query, via https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation.  (2) Beyond that, I did briefly examine your work as shown in the images.  There wasn't enough work shown to complete - you would have to go further in your approach.

Answer (score 2):

There are $4$ places to put the $8$, $3$ to put the $9$ after that and $8×8$ ways to assign the other two digits. Thus there are $4×3×8×8=768$ admissible numbers.

Comment: well, but i am doing a different way, i need to resover in that way

Answer (score 1):

There are $4\cdot 3 = 12$ ways to choose which digits will be the $8$ and the $9$ respectively, and $8^{2} = 64$ ways to choose the remaining digits (we don't have to worry about leading zeroes because the range is from $1$ to $10,000$). Thus, the answer is $\boxed{12\cdot 64 = 768.}$

Comment: well, but i am doing a different way, i need to resover in that way